# Stack Overflow vs. Google Search

Tags: discussion, answers, google

Sometimes I wonder why people answer questions in cases where it is too obvious that the OP didn't make a single attempt to find something on Google.

Just now I was reading a quite fresh question that already had a couple of answers. Simply googling the title of the question made me find several good explanations. I also noted that the question itself was the first search result.

When it is too obvious that the OP used Stack Overflow as his first source of information, isn't it better not to answer the question?

**PRO:**
Of course it is good that questions are answered fast and that one can find them easily on Google.

**CON:** On the other hand such cases can encourage users to use Stack Overflow as their first source of information instead of doing some research on their own. Also users giving an answer could use their time to answer other questions (that one cannot solved by a single Google search).

As Qui pointed out, this topic is discussed also [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33376/is-it-bad-to-ask-google-searchable-questions-on-stack-overflow). However, I am more concerned about the answers and not the question. Beginners often just do not know what so search for and ask a question that in principle could be solved easily.

On the other hand, users that know the answer should know better. I personally think that in some cases I can help the OP more by simply putting a link as comment instead of writing my own answer. In the worst case, an acceptable answer could even prevent the OP from doing further reading.

Comment: [Speaking of the devil](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33376/is-it-bad-to-ask-google-searchable-questions-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: @Qiu I knew that this must be discussed somewhere, just didnt know what to search for ;)  haha

Comment: I can guess reasons for downvotes, nevertheless I would be nice if downvoters would comment

Answer (score 5):

The fact that information is easily available elsewhere isn't **alone** a reason for something to be off-topic for Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is supposed to be a repository of questions and answers: If someone is able to write a **good, clear, on-topic** question that **hasn't already been asked** on Stack Overflow, and can illustrate that they made a reasonable attempt to research their question (perhaps just failing to understand what terms to search), then it's absolutely appropriate to answer that question. Alternatively, if you feel that a question "does not show any research effort", as is mentioned in the hover text for the downvote button, then it's perfectly appropriate to downvote and move on. The judgement call is ultimately going to be somewhat subjective and can only really be made on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: I agree, and I was about to answer something along these lines. The key in judging questions is to **focus on their content** and not to make any further assumptions.

Comment: You seem to be contradicting yourself: "The fact that information is available elsewhere isn't alone a reason for something being off-topic for Stack Overflow" along with "and can illustrate that they made a reasonable attempt to research their question." What do you mean by research if not that they tried to find it somewhere else?

Comment: My point is that it's possible for something to be available elsewhere, but for someone with incomplete understanding to make a reasonable effort and still not find it. There simply isn't going to be a hard and fast rule for "how google-able" a question can be before it's off topic - it's subjective. But others put it better in the post linked in the comments above - I'd recommend reading that.

Comment: I agree for the most parts. However, I was referring to cases where it really is obvious that no reasonable research effort was made. I mean when I type the title in google and find dozens of good answers elsewhere, I definitely would call the question "google-able". Also I am rather thinking about downvoting answers (not the question) when they do not mention other (potentially better) sources when they exist. Of course I never did it, but I would like to hear others opinion.